# sort object using comparable for arraylist of objects

Tags: java, sorting, collections

Hi I have a country class and that contains a countryLanguage set.
I want to sort the language for each country.
I am createing view page. country and his corresponding language.
county is ok but its language are not in sorted order.
I am confused in which class i have use compartor and how.

```
public class Country implements Serializable{
private Set<CountryLanguage> countryLanguage = new HashSet<CountryLanguage>(0);
//...
}
public class CountryLanguage {
private CountryLanguageID countryLangPK = new CountryLanguageID();
//...
}
```

composit id class

```
   public class CountryLanguageID implements Serializable,Comparable<CountryLanguageID>{

private Country country;
private Language language;

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
public Country getCountry() {
    return country;
}
public void setCountry(Country country) {
    this.country = country;
}

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
public Language getLanguage() {
    return language;
}
public void setLanguage(Language language) {
    this.language = language;
}

public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    CountryLanguageID that = (CountryLanguageID) o;

    if (country != null ? !country.equals(that.country) : that.country != null){
        return false;
    }
    if (language != null ? !language.equals(that.language) : that.language != null){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
public int hashCode() {
    int result;
    result = (country != null ? country.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (language != null ? language.hashCode() : 0);
    return result;
}
@Override
public int compareTo(CountryLanguageID o) {

    //return this.language.compareTo(o.language);
    return this.getLanguage().getLanguageName().compareTo(o.getLanguage().getLanguageName());
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `TreeSet` instead of `HashSet` to keep `countryLanguage`:

```
private Set<CountryLanguage> countryLanguage = new TreeSet<CountryLanguage>(0);
```

The elements of `TreeSet` are ordered using their natural ordering or can be ordered by using a `Comparator`, typically provided at `TreeSet` creation time.

If you want to go with `natural ordering` of `CountryLanguage`, make `CountryLanguage` implement `Comparable`:

```
public class CountryLanguage implements Comparable<CountryLanguage>{

@Override
public int compareTo(CountryLanguage cl) {
    // Comparison logic
}
...
}
```

And if you want to use a `Comparator` to order elements of `countryLanguage`, define a comparator:

```
private static final Comparator<CountryLanguage> COMP = new Comparator<CountryLanguage>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(CountryLanguage o1, CountryLanguage o2) {
            // Compare o1 with o2
        }
};
```

and use it while creating your `TreeSet`:

```
 private Set<CountryLanguage> countryLanguage = new TreeSet<CountryLanguage>(COMP);
```

**EDIT:**

Your `set` is of type `CountryLanguage`. So in order to sort the elements of `Set<CountryLanguage> countryLanguage`, you need to make `CountryLanguage` implement `Comparable` (but you have defined `CountryLanguageID` to implement `Comparable`):

And while comparing instances of `CountryLanguage`, you can use `CountryLanguageID` property for comparison:

```
public class CountryLanguage implements Comparable<CountryLanguage>{
private CountryLanguageID countryLangPK = new CountryLanguageID();
...    
@Override
public int compareTo(CountryLanguage cl) {
return this.countryLangPK.getLanguage().getLanguageName().compareTo(cl.getCountryLangPK().getLanguage().getLanguageName());
}
...
}
```

Comment: its not working. I have tried both of logics. In the first logic I written comparision login in countryLanguage class as this.getCountryLangPK().getLanguage().getLanguageName().compareTo(o2.getCountryLangPK().getLanguage().getLanguageName()); any more suggessions is appriceated

Comment: I have tried  overriding compareTo in country,countryLanguage,countryLanguageId and language class but fail to get country object with sorted language, should I use @Sort.

Comment: you have `Country` with a set of `CountryLanguage` and your CountryLanguage is implementing `Comparable` as it was shown in my answer (to compare CountryLanguage you can use any prop of it, mine was just an example).Now when you create a `new Country` and you start putting `CountryLanguage` into the set, the `TreeSet` itself will maintain the ordering of the elements.there is no need to sort the elements using a different sort method.And again, your set is of type `CountryLanguage`, so CountryLanguage should implement Comparable.